# Existe alguma maneira de renderizar uma view do Laravel para uma string?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de salvar o retorno de uma view no Laravel em uma `string`.

Geralmente, retornamos a `view` para poder "imprimir" o resultado de uma ação na página:

```
 function getIndex() {
      return view('hello');
 }
```

Tentei salvar numa variável, porém está retornando `Illuminate\View\View(Object)` quando executo um `var_dump`.

Exemplo do que tenho até o momento:

```
 $view = view('hello');

 var_dump($view); // retorna Object
```

Existe alguma maneira de atribuir a `string` da `view` a uma variável?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Laravel, a `View` implementa um método chamado `__toString`. Com ele é possível obter uma `string` a partir de um objeto quando você faz um cast para `string`.

Então mude seu código para:

```
$view = (string) view('hello');

var_dump($view);
```

Ainda também é possível chamar o método `view('hello')->render()`.

Nas versões anteriores ao Laravel 5, você tinha que chamar `View::make('hello')->render()`.